# $\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_{2k} +\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}a_{2k+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

> I would like to show that 
>   \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_{2k} + 
>   \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}a_{2k+1}\\
> \end{align}
>
> - I'm interested in more ways of prove it

**My proof.**

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}&=\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \text{ is even }}}^{n} a_{k}+\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k \text{ is odd }}}^{n} a_{k}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k=2k' \text{ with } k'\in\mathbb{Z}}}^{n} a_{k}+\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k=2k'+1 \text{ with } k'\in\mathbb{Z}}}^{n} a_{k}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k'=\frac{k}{2} }}^{n} a_{2k'}+\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k'=\frac{k-1}{2} }}^{n} a_{2k'+1}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k'=\frac{k}{2}\\ k=0 \implies k'=0 \\ k=n \implies k'=\frac{n}{2}}}^{n} a_{2k'}+\sum_{\substack{k=0 \\ k'=\frac{k-1}{2}\\ \text{since k is odd can start with 1 and not 0 } k=1 \implies k'=0 \\ k=n \implies k'=\dfrac{n-1}{2}  }}^{n} a_{2k'+1}\\
&=\sum_{k'=0}^{ n/2 } a_{2k'} + 
  \sum_{k'=0}^{ (n-1)/2 }a_{2k'+1}\\
&\text{If $n$ is even, then $\frac{(n−1)}{2}$ is not an integer, which is why we  need the floor.}\\
&\text{Similarly, if $n$ is odd, then $\frac{n}{2}$ is not an integer}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_{2k} + 
  \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}a_{2k+1}
\end{align}

- Is my proof correct
- I'm interested in more ways of prove it

Comment: so that you don't have to worry that: even number may take odd value and vice versa

Comment: also, a small typo in the first line of your proof: in the second summation, $k$ should start from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $(n-1)/2$ is not an integer, which is why you need the floor. Similarly, if $n$ is odd, then $n/2$ is not an integer.

Comment: @HowDoIMath yes i see that's why i have to add floor thanks. what about my proof

Comment: well, shoot.  Yes, your idea is correct and what you are trying to express is clear.  I'm not sure your notation of indexing is  technically legitimate however.  Normally one really shouldn't get bogged do in details like that.  However in this case what you are trying to prove is simply "The sum of all terms is the sum of the even terms plus the sum of the odd terms" (which is obvious) and your proof is verifying that the reindexing is valid.

Comment: Okay, where you say "with k' $\in$ Z", I, personally would say "for some k' $\in$ Z".  It's a *minor* point, but "with k" implies (to me at least) that you are trying to us *all* integers rather than just the ones were 2k' (or 2k' + 1) are between 0 and n.

Comment: @fleablood  would please post version of solution with notation of indexing is technically legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_{2k}= \sum_{i=0; i\ is\  even}^{2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_{i} = \sum_{i=0; i\ is\  even}^{n} a_{i} = \sum_{k=0; k\ is\  even}^{n} a_{k}$

$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} a_{2k + 1}= \sum_{i=0; i\ is\  odd}^{2\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor + 1} a_{i} = \sum_{i=0; i\ is\  odd}^{n} a_{i}= \sum_{k=0; k\ is\  odd}^{n} a_{k}$

$\sum_{k=0}^n a_n = \sum_{k=0; k\ is\  even}^{n} a_{k} + \sum_{k=0; k\ is\  odd}^{n} a_{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} a_{2k + 1}$

Comment: i think in the second line $i=1$ not $0$ since $i=2k+1$

Answer (score 0):

**If $n$ is odd, i.e. $n=2m+1$,**

then $k=0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 2m+1=\underbrace{(0, 2, 4, 6, .., \color{blue}{2m})}_{\underset{k=0, 1, ..., \lfloor n/2\rfloor}{2k}},(\underbrace{1, 3, 5, ..., 2m-1, \color{red}{2m+1}}_{\underset{k=0, 1, ..., \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}{ 2k+1}})$
as
$$\begin{align}
&2\bigg\lfloor \frac n2 \bigg\rfloor&&=2\bigg\lfloor \frac {2m+1}2\bigg\rfloor&&=2\bigg\lfloor m+\frac 12 \bigg\rfloor&&=\color{blue}{2m}\\
&2\bigg\lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \bigg\rfloor+1&&=2\bigg\lfloor\frac{2m}2\bigg\rfloor+1&&&&=\color{red}{2m+1}\end{align}$$

**If $n$ is even, i.e. $n=2m$,**

then 
$k=0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 2m=\underbrace{(0, 2, 4, 6, .., \color{green}{2m})}_{\underset{k=0, 1, ..., \lfloor n/2\rfloor}{2k}},(\underbrace{1, 3, 5, ..., \color{orange}{2m-1}}_{\underset{k=0, 1, ..., \lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}{ 2k+1}})$
as
$$\begin{align}
&2\bigg\lfloor \frac n2 \bigg\rfloor&&=2\bigg\lfloor \frac {2m}2\bigg\rfloor&&=\color{green}{2m}\\
&2\bigg\lfloor \frac {n-1}2 \bigg\rfloor+1&&=2\bigg\lfloor\frac{2m-1}2\bigg\rfloor+1=2\underbrace{\bigg\lfloor m-\frac12\bigg\rfloor}_{m-1}+1=2(m-1)+1&&=\color{orange}{2m-1}\end{align}$$

**Hence** the formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} a_{2k} + 
  \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}a_{2k+1}\\$$
holds irrespective of whether $n$ is odd or even.